# Modeling relational database tables for tracking status of stages and tasks within stages

Tags: web, database-design, relational-database

I'm trying to model a relational database for a web-based, migration/project tracking app. In the interface, I want to display all of the stages of the project and all the tasks within those stages - for example:

```
Stage 1: Planning do these things
  Task 1: do this planning activity first
  Task 2: do this planning activity second
Stage 2: Start coding based on requirements
  Task 1: do this coding requirement first
  Task 2: do this coding requirement second
```

At the end of each task I would have a drop-down for users to select the status of each task (Not-Started, In-Progress, Blocked, Completed)

For tables to model the tasks that will populate the interface, I'm thinking something like these:

```
tbl: Task
  taskID
  task
```

The tables for storing projects and statuses would look something like this:

```
    tbl: Migration
      MigrationID
      Migration_Name
      StatusID

    tbl: Status
      StatusID:
      s1_t1
      s1_t2
      s1_t3
      s2_t1
      s2_t2
```

So Migration table is the primary table and it would have a 1-to-1 relationship with Status table. I believe that the relationship between Status table and Migration table would be a one-to-many. I'm thinking I need some other relational tables just to track many-to-many relationships also.

Hope someone can provide guidance, I'm feeling out of my league at this point.

Here is the user flow:

[image]

Here is visio diagram of what I'm thinking so far:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why you have 5 status fields in the Status table.

Comment: Gilbert, my thought was that each of those statuses fields in the statuses table relates to the status of a corresponding task in the task table. Example: s1_t1 refers to the first task in the first stage. I’m probably mixed up, I wanted to do that because when the user opens a page for their project, they should see all tasks from the task table and the corresponding status for each task from the status table. Please correct me if this isn’t the best way

Comment: The status table should hold a single status and a status timestamp.  If the task had 5 status changes, the status table would hold 5 rows.  The status row needs a pointer back to the task.  Your other tables look fine, except don't name columns ID and make table names singular.  Name your primary key columns StageID, TaskID, ProjectID.  These names make your joins a lot less confusing.

Comment: I changed primary keys and table names as recommended. To clarify, each project has multiple tasks, each task has a state (Completed, In-Progress). User clicks a project on the Projects page and all of the tasks for that project and the status for each task displays. The user can change the status of any task. That is what I'm trying to model the tbls on. The migration tbl has a foreign key statusID that corresponds to the primary key in the Status tbl. Each column in the Status tbl corresponds to a different task status. With 40 tasks per project, then status tbl has 40+ columns. Your ideas?

Comment: I'm not understanding your comment and I don't understand what the Migration table represents.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Migration and Project interchangeably. The Migration/Project tracking table is used to track the status of all migrations/projects we are working on. It holds details about the migrations like the name of the item being migrated, migration owner, is it IaaS or PaaS model, the OS type, and additionally it contains a reference to the status table for each migration. So each project/migration has approx 40 tasks that need to be completed before it is migrated. The Status tbl has columns for each task the columns hold statuses.   I will update images above for better example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Migration, Member, Stage, and Task tables look fine.

Your Status table should look like this:

```
Status
------
Status ID
Status
```

The rows would look like this:

```
Status ID | Status
------------------------
        1 | Not Started
        2 | In Progress
        3 | Blocked
        4 | Completed
```

You can easily add additional statuses.  (Awaiting Review, Reviewed, etc.)  If the order of the statuses is important, add another int column to index the statuses.

```
Status ID | Status      | Status Index
--------------------------------------
        1 | Not Started |         1000
        2 | In Progress |         2000
        3 | Blocked     |         3000
        4 | Completed   |         4000
```

With large gaps in the status index, you could add many new statuses, and still maintain a status order.

There's an implicit many to many relationship between Tasks and Status.  The status of a task changes over time, and it's important to keep track of the status changes.

So, we create a junction table between Tasks and Status.

```
TaskStatus
----------
TaskStatus ID
Task ID
Status ID
Create Timestamp
```

where TaskStatus ID is an auto-incrementing integer that acts as the blind primary key for the table.  The Task ID, Status ID, and Create Timestamp descending together form a unique index.

Each task will create at least 4 rows on the TaskStatus table.  For an entire project / migration, you can have hundreds of TaskStatus rows.  This way, you don't have to worry about the number of status columns.  You have one status column, which can contain as many task statuses as you can imagine.

Comment: Thanks Gilbert, I forgot about the TaskStatus junction table. That helps. I will probably need to add another 1-to-1 related table for some additional details my boss just brought up, but I think this will help me to implement those also.